# HTML eMail error with HTML 4.01

Tags: html, email

I'm working on some oracle code to generate an HTML eMail.  It's mostly working, but I took the resulting HTML and placed it in Dreamweaver CS6 to use the validation.  I get a few errors:

1) No Character encoding declared at document level [HTML 4.01]

2) element "U" undefined [HTML 4.01]

The html code  is generated automatically by a rich text editor widget.  Should I use something other than HTML 4.01?  I'm not too savvy with HTML Header code.

Here's the HTML code that is generated from my test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Saint Susanna Parish Mailing</title>
    </head>        
    <body>
        <p>This is normal text</p>
        <p>
            <strong>This is bold</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <u>This is Underscored</u>
        </p>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <span style="color:#ff0000;">This is numbered</span>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <ul>
            <li>This is bulleted</li>
        </ul>
        <p style="text-align: center;">This is centered</p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-size:18px;"><span style="font-family: times new roman,times,serif;">This is a new font</span></span>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: right;">This is right justified</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I think the encoding can be specified in the mail headers, so I wouldn't worry too much about that. The `u` was [deprecated in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp) but not obsolete, so that's where the validator seems to be wrong. I wouldn't underline text, though, because obviously that text could easily be mistaken for a link. If you need to, and you don't want to use `<u>`, you can use an inline `text-decoration` style.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  So with your comment "I think the encoding can be specified in the mail headers" are you saying that I should change something in my header or to ignore the validator's warning?

Comment: Indeed. I've supplied the info in an answer, since it became, well, an actual complete answer. :)

Comment: I don't get why the OP accepted the totally wrong answer as the solution.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

U can do a lot of control by using classes etc - declared in a style.css file that u call first as well.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>   - HTML 5

    <b> and </b> can replace strong to save characters

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" title="Standard Style">
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I add a style sheet for an html eMail?

Comment: That's a really bad idea when it comes to email templates. Every email client works in a different way. Stick to the basics. Even the horrible `tables` are a good way to avoid problems.

Comment: External files will also cause problems, if even loaded.

Comment: External files won't be loaded at all by most mail clients. Even an inline `<style>` tag is bound to be ignored. You'll have to stick to inline style attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the encoding can -and must- be specified in the mail headers, so I would ignore that warning.

The article [The Importance of Content-Type Character Encoding in HTML Emails](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails) says:

> [The client] will display the email based on what Content-Type has been set.
>   However, email clients read the Content-Type value that is set in the
>   email header and they completely ignore the META tag that is within
>   the HTML.

So that suggests that you should add the proper header, and can safely ignore the validator's warning, although it can't hurt at all to add the meta tag as well.

If you want a second opinion, you can try the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), although that one might also complain about missing content types. After all, these validators don't know what headers you are going to supply.

Different rules apply to HTML mail anyway. Clients ignore basically everything that is outside of the body. They also filter out all kinds of attributes, won't allow JavaScript and fully ignore external stylesheets and inline style tags.

The `<u>` tag was [deprecated in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp) but not obsolete. In that case the validator seems to be wrong, so I would ignore that warning as well. I wouldn't underline text at all though, because obviously that text could easily be mistaken for a link. If you need to, and you don't want to use `<u>`, you can use an inline `text-decoration` style.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the suggested text to the header and that removed the validation error.  Thanks.  As part of my test, I tried to use every part of the oracle rich text widget.  The likelihood of someone using and underscore is remote.  Thanks for the help